# c# copy object (CheckedListBox) not reference

Tags: c#, reference, copy, checkedlistbox

I work on windows form application in C#(ver 4.0)

I want to copy a CheckedListBox, but not as reference. I want that every change in the CheckedListBox should not effect my object, just assign once, then no reference.

Following is my code:

```
public struct SmartFilter
{
    public int from, to;
    public CheckedListBox cmb;            

}
var temp = new SmartFilter();
    temp.from = Convert.ToInt32(cbNumber2From.SelectedItem);
    temp.to = Convert.ToInt32(cbNumber2To.SelectedItem);

    temp.cmb = cbNumbers2;
```

when I get to the last line

```
temp.cmb = cbNumbers2;
```

I want to save a copy in `temp.cmb` (CheckedListBox) , but after that every change in the window effects my object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, basically - `CheckedListBox` isn't cloneable.

How would you expect it to operate? It's an on-screen control... would you expect the clone to just have no parent window, and not be on-screen? How much of the state of the `CheckedListBox` are you interested in? Maybe you should be copying just that aspect instead of the whole `CheckedListBox`.

As a side-note, mutable structs are almost always a bad idea, as are public fields.

Comment: i want to save only the data in this checkedlistbox, so i will save only the data in different fields , thanks

Comment: @Haim: Right. That makes a lot more sense. It's generally a bad idea to take a dependency on a UI component if you're only interested in the data within it.